# How to launch a Python/Tkinter dialog box that self-destructs?

Tags: python, tkinter

Ok, I would like to put together a Python/Tkinter dialog box that displays a simple message and self-destructs after N seconds. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `after` function to call a function after a delay elapsed and the `destroy` to close the window.

Here is an example

```
from Tkinter import Label, Tk
root = Tk()
prompt = 'hello'
label1 = Label(root, text=prompt, width=len(prompt))
label1.pack()

def close_after_2s():
    root.destroy()

root.after(2000, close_after_2s)
root.mainloop()
```

Update: The after docstring says:

> Call function once after given time.
>       MS specifies the time in milliseconds. 
>       FUNC gives the function which shall be called. 
>       Additional parameters are given as parameters to the function call.
>       Return identifier to cancel scheduling with after_cancel.

Comment: Thanks--very helpful! Can you point me to reference documentation for the after() function?

Comment: Also, the next step is to update the contents of the label. Is there some trick to this? I tried 'label1.set('new text');label1.pack()' to no avail...

Comment: @Stephen Gross - I found docs here: http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/universal.html

Comment: Is there some restriction on the number of times you can call root.after() ? I wrote 'root.after(1000, do_this); root.after(2000, do_that)' and it appears to only execute the latter function. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: no, there is no limit to how many times you can call `root.after()`. Unfortunately, without seeing your code it's impossible to say what you did wrong.

Answer (score 1):

you could also use a thread.
this example uses a Timer to call destroy() after a specified amount of time.

```
import threading
import Tkinter


root = Tkinter.Tk()
Tkinter.Frame(root, width=250, height=100).pack()
Tkinter.Label(root, text='Hello').place(x=10, y=10)

threading.Timer(3.0, root.destroy).start()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Using threads is way too much overhead for such a simple problem, and could lead to a crash since Tkinter isn't thread safe.